# Let $b_n$ decrease monotonically to zero, prove $\sum b_nz^n$ converges for $|z|\leq 1$ and $z\neq 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Let $b_n$ be a sequence which decreases monotonically to zero, prove $\sum b_nz^n$ converges for $|z|\leq 1$ and $z\neq 1$.

So I was able to prove it converges on the open unit disk in the complex plane, but except for a few special points on the boundary, such as $-1$ and $i$, where I was able to use the alternating series test, I can't seem to prove it converges in general on the boundary minus $z=1$.

I feel I have to somehow use the fact that all the numbers on the unit circle except $z=1$ rotate around and around as you raise them to higher and higher powers, thus you get the real and imaginary parts of your series to alternate between sets of positive and negative terms, but in a very irregular way for most initial angles.

I tried to simplify the problem by breaking the series into its real and imaginary parts, and then trying to prove they each converge separately, but I still can't prove either converges:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_ne^{n\theta i} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n\cos(n\theta) +i\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n\sin(n\theta).$$

Comment: Use Dirichlet's test: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test

Comment: @njguliyev oh nice, that does it right there, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $|z| \le 1$, $z \ne 1$, we have:
$$
\left|\sum_{k=0}^n z^k\right| = \left|\frac{1 - z^{k+1}}{1 - z}\right| \le \frac{2}{|1 - z|}
$$

Thus, by [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n z^n$ converges for $|z| \le 1$, $z \ne 1$.